Calling R function in Julia
I would like to run an R function from a script in Julia. I am able to do the reverse, call a Julia function in R, by do the following:
library(JuliaCall)
julia_source("bin/julia_function.jl") which has a function "juliaFunction". 

out <- julia_call("juliaFunction", input1, input2)

However, I couldn't figure out how to call an R function from within Julia. It is not a function from a library, which I know can be called using RCall package.
As an example, in fun.R
my_function <- function(fname) {
  paste(fname, "Griffin")
}

Then in a Julia script I would like to call my_function. How would I do that?
Also, I would like to be able to call the Julia script from command line so wouldn't want to use the R REPL mode.
Thanks in advance.
Tried RCall and include("fun.R") but neither are what I need.

This might help: https://juliainterop.github.io/RCall.jl/stable/gettingstarted/

@moodymudskipper Thank you but they only mention how to load a library and call a function from the library but not how to load a function from a file into Julia

Can't you call source() ? Something like R""""source(your_file);fun(1)"""

Suppose you have this data frame and want to plot it in R:
using Distributions, DataFrames, Random
df = DataFrame(permutedims(rand(MvNormal([1 0.75; 0.75 1]), 1000)), :auto)

You can do now:
using RCall
@rlibrary ggplot2
display(ggplot(df,aes(x=:x1,y=:x2)) + geom_point())

Note that in the code above Symbols are used in those R code constructs where lazy parameter evaluation takes place.
Another option is interpolation combined with string macros:
R"library(ggplot2)"
R"ggplot($df,aes(x=x1,y=x2)) + geom_point()"

Coming to your use case you could make:
R"source('fun.R')"

Now you can call the function as:
julia> R"res <- my_function(\"Jack \")"
RObject{StrSxp}
[1] "Jack  Griffin"


julia> @rget res
"Jack  Griffin"

References

the plotting code is from my GitHub repo https://github.com/pszufe/2024_MIT_18.S097_Introduction-to-Julia-for-Data-Science

